# xs:any in xs:all tag for xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a scenario where I need a xsd which is used for validating few bunch of xml's which have few things in common. For example,

xml1:

```
<myXml1>
<myTag>
<someTag>..</someTag>
<requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
<someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
<myXml1>
```

xml2:

```
<myXml1>
<myTag>
<requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
<otherTag>..</otherTag>
</myTag>
<myXml1>
```

I am in need of a common xsd so as to validate both the xmls's which have "`requiredTag`" in common and read its value.

I tried using `<xs:any>` but it is supported only in `xs:sequence` and not in `xs:all`. My `requiredTag` can be anywhere under `myTag`.

I would like to use this xsd to create classes using jaxb for reading the value.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can validate with XSD 1.1, you can use:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="myTagType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            <xs:element name="requiredTag" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 ...
</xs:schema>
```

Unfortunately this fails in XSD 1.0 because it violates the [Unique Particle Atribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#non-ambig) constraint.

One workaround consists in using different namespaces for the `any` elements and `requiredTag`. Declare a schema with a namespace for the required tag:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns="required-tag-ns" 
           targetNamespace="required-tag-ns">
    <xs:element name="requiredTag" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Now import that into your schema (you will need a prefix for one of them):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="any-tag-ns" 
           xmlns="any-tag-ns" 
           xmlns:r="required-tag-ns">

    <xs:import namespace="required-tag-ns" schemaLocation="required.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType name="myTagType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="any-tag-ns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            <xs:element ref="r:requiredTag"/> <!-- now it works in 1.0 because the ambiguity was removed -->
            <xs:any namespace="any-tag-ns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   ...
</xs:schema>
```

Either the XSD 1.1 schema, or the XSD 1.0 schema above will validate these cases:

```
<myTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
</myTag>
<myTag>
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
</myTag>
<myTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
<myTag>
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
<myTag>
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
```

But they will *not* validate these cases:

```
<myTag> <!-- missing requiredTag -->
    <someTag>..</someTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
<myTag> <!-- too many requiredTags -->
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
    <requiredTag>..</requiredTag>
    <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
</myTag>
```

In the XSD 1.1 version you won't need the namespaces. In the XSD 1.0 solution your instance will have to qualify the `requiredTag` with its namespace:

```
<myXml xmlns="any-tag-ns"
       xmlns:r="required-tag-ns"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="any-tag-ns your-schema-file.xsd">

    <myTag>
        <someTag>..</someTag>
        <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
        <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
        <r:requiredTag>..</r:requiredTag>
        <someotherTag>..</someotherTag>
    </myTag>
    ...
</myXml>
```